# How to create a machine learning/visualization module (Pandas/Matplotlib) for use with Jupiter-Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, module, jupyter-notebook

My team and I are making a Jupyter Notebook for machine learning and data science work. I'm managing software design so I want to make sure I do this correctly and properly.

Our machine learning leverages common data science libraries:
-pandas
-sklearn
-numpy
-matplotlib

The Notebook deliverable is meant to be used by people with little to no coding expertise. We hope to accomplish this with a variety of Jupyter widgets. To keep the code away from the innocent end-user, we want to import a module into the notebook and have the code in the notebook used for creating widgets wrapping the data science.

For example, we would run a machine learning algorithm on a data frame that processes several countries' CO2 emissions to look at climate change. And we want to make a visualization for which countries emit the most. The code for the ML would be in the imported module. The Notebook would import the module and have widget functions to make calls to the module.

I'd like some feedback on this design. I'm considering taking our ML code and creating the module in PyCharm. I haven't tested if matplotlib visualizations work in PyCharm as well as it works in Jupyter. Any advice and precautions to keep in mind are appreciated.

We've already made most of the ML code across a few notebooks. We're looking to migrate over to a class-based module import to the notebook. I'm looking into packaging and importing into Jupyter to make sure this is possible, clean, and modular.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is but if you're looking for opinions on design, this probably isn't the place for it. Creating a module and importing that into a jupyter notebook is very common. There's nothing stopping you from writing your ML widgets in some other code and just importing the higher-level interfacing tools into a notebook and generating results/graphs there. That's very common in fact.

Comment: Thats reassuring to hear. I wasn't sure where the best place to get feedback on this would be, but comments like that do help. Before my team puts all this effort in I want to ensure they have a end goal they can actually meet. @BrianJoseph